# Determine InstallPath using REG QUERY

Tags: batch-file, registry

I am using a batch file to determine the `InstallPath` of R using `REG QUERY`:

```
@echo off

REM get path
for /f "tokens=2*" %%a in ('REG QUERY "HKCU\Software\R-Core\R64" /v InstallPath') do set "RPath=%%~b"

set "var=\bin\R.exe --no-save"
set "R=%RPath%%var%"

REM start R fed with a script
%R% < "path.to.some.rfile.r"
```

This used to work perfectly until I updated R to version 3.4.1 which writes the key of `InstallPath` to a subfolder in the windows registry.

Since this subfolder is named by the version of R and I want the batch file to work independently from the R-version, I want to get `InstallPath` from any existing subfolder. How could I mangage to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could query all values of a registry key and its subkeys recursively by specifying the `query /s` command-line switch when executing the `reg` command-line tool. The following batch-script retrieves the data of the first registry value found named `InstallPath` in registry key `HKCU\Software\R-Core\R64` or any of its subkeys.

```
@echo off

set "key=hkcu\software\r-core\r64"
set "scr=path.to.some.rfile.r"
set "val=installpath"
set "bin=bin\r.exe"
set "arg=--no-save"
set "rPath="

:: Retrieve the installation directory path of R from the registry
for /f "tokens=2,*" %%i in ('reg query "%key%" /v "%val%" /s') do (
  if not defined rPath (
    set "rPath=%%~j"
  )
)
set "r=%rPath%\%bin% %arg%"

:: The contents of some script file is fed to the standard input stream of R 
%r% 0<"%scr%"
```

Depending on how R installs itself, you could also try to use the `where` command to retrieve the fully qualified path of the R binary instead of querying values from the registry.

```
for /f "delims=" %%e in ('where r') do set "r=%%~e"
```

Comment: Unluckily `where` does not work, but your batch script works like a charm.